# Mediaplayer does not stop

Tags: android, kotlin, android-mediaplayer

While not 100% I have the mediaplayer playing, however now it won't stop. I get the following error

> E/ExtMediaPlayer-JNI: QCMediaPlayer could not be located....
> E/MediaPlayer-JNI: JNIMediaPlayerFactory: bIsQCMediaPlayerPresent 0
> E/ExtMediaPlayer-JNI: QCMediaPlayer could not be located....
> E/MediaPlayer-JNI: JNIMediaPlayerFactory: bIsQCMediaPlayerPresent 0
> E/MediaPlayer: stop called in state 1, mPlayer(0x0)
> error (-38, 0) W/MediaPlayer: mediaplayer went away with unhandled events

```
package com.radiomedia.drn1


import android.media.AudioManager
import android.media.MediaPlayer
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(){



    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)



        playButton.setOnClickListener(object: View.OnClickListener {
            override fun onClick(v: View?) {


                if(playButton.text.toString()=="Pause") {
                    media().play()
               
                }
                else{
                    media().stop()
                }

            }

        })

    }




}

class media(){
    val mp = MediaPlayer()

   fun play(){
        val url = "http://stream.radiomedia.com.au:8003/stream" // your URL here
        mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC)
        mp.setDataSource(url)
        mp.prepare() // might take long! (for buffering, etc)

        mp.start()
    }
    fun stop(){
        mp.stop()
        mp.release()
    }


}
```

Comment: Hi Russell. How are you getting on with this? There is an answer below that could do with your attention. While it is not strictly mandatory to answer or vote here, the community would collapse if no-one did so.

Answer (score 1):

You are instantiating completely different instances of `MediaPlayer`. By calling `media()`, you're creating a new instance of the `media` class, which then creates a new instance of `MediaPlayer` as its property `mp`. But since this `media` instance is not a property of `MainActivity`, it goes out of scope when the on-click listener returns.

The underlying media player then gets freed, which explains the error you're seeing. But even without that error, calling stop would not have any effect, since you're not calling it on the running MediaPlayer, but a completely new one.

To achieve what you want, you'd need to add a property in `MainActivity`, something like:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(){

    private lateinit var mMedia: media

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        mMedia = media()


        playButton.setOnClickListener(object: View.OnClickListener {
            override fun onClick(v: View?) {

                if(playButton.text.toString()=="Pause") {
                    // Go back to start to replay
                    mMedia.seekTo(0)
                    mMedia.start()
                }
                else{
                    // Stopping prevents MediaPlayer to be played again. Use pause() instead
                    mMedia.pause()
                }
            }
        })
    }
}
```